# Custom-naming XML tags using instance value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dto

I am working on this ASP.NET Api, where data is obtained through GET requests, formatted as XML.

right now, all xml nodes are generated using the code elements (class names, property names, etc). I can, if I wish, use attributes such as [XmlType(TypeName = "DesiredName")] to change those node names, but still, it will be a mapping 1-to-1 with the names I use in the code.

I have a specific object type which I would like to format using the actual runtime values, as opposed to the compile-time symbols.

Here are the classes:

```
public class RootClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
    // Other Fields
}
```

Let's say that I have a couple properties, which have propertyTypes "Type1", "Type2", "Type3"

My desired Xml looks like this:

```
<RootClass>
    <ID>23</ID>
    <Properties>
        <Type1>
            <Property>
                // Other Fields
            </Property>
            <Property>
                // Other Fields
            </Property>
        </Type1>
        <Type2>
            <Property>
                // Other Fields
            </Property>
        </Type2>
    </Properties>
</RootType>
```

As you can see, one of the nodes would be named depending on the values, not the schema. I can easily do the grouping through code when mapping from the Model to the DTOs, and I have complete control over the DTO's classes, so I can change them as desired to get my expected XML.

First, is this even possible?

If it is, what should my class structure (and Attributes) look like to achieve this (Dictionaries of lists? custom collections?)

And if it isn't, What other options do I have to achieve something as close as possible to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RootClass root = new RootClass()
            {
                ID = "23",
                Properties = new List<Property>() {
                    new Property() { PropertyType = "Type1", Properties = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C"} },
                    new Property() { PropertyType = "Type2", Properties = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C"} }
                }
            };

            XElement rootClass = new XElement("RootClass", new object[] {
                new XElement("ID", root.ID),
                new XElement("Properties")
            });

            XElement properties = rootClass.Element("Properties");
            int count = 1;
            foreach (Property property in root.Properties)
            {
                XElement type = new XElement(property.PropertyType);
                properties.Add(type);
                foreach (string p in property.Properties)
                {
                    XElement strProperty = new XElement("Property", new object[] {
                        new XElement(p, count++)
                    });
                    type.Add(strProperty);
                }
            }

            rootClass.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class RootClass
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public class Property
    {
        public string PropertyType { get; set; }
        public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
    }
}
```